# AJAX POST - do I need to send a response?

Tags: ajax, django, post, httpresponse

I have written an AJAX function that sends a POST request to my server (running Django 1.9).

The request should trigger a process on the server - no need for the client to do anything. I therefore didn't add a `return` in the post method of my view.

However, in the output of my server I found some error messages about that:

```
Internal Server Error: <url>
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/.../python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in get_response  
    % (callback.__module__, view_name))  
ValueError: The view <view> didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.  
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: <url>  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/.../python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in get_response  
    % (callback.__module__, view_name))  
ValueError: The view <view> didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.  
[01/Feb/2016 00:30:28] "POST <url> HTTP/1.1" 500 14165
```

Therefore I added

```
return HttpResponse('')
```

to the method.

However, this seems a bit obsolete to me.

- Is it necessary to send a response to a POST request?
- If yes, what is the most basic response I can send? (Is it the one I used?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't necessary to send any response to any request. You can just close connection, but...

- django will throw an error that you haven't send any response (even empty one)
- HTTP server (nginx, apache or something else) expects from you to send anything (that's one of the reasons why django will send in response an error)
- your JavaScript will treat request as failed one

Most minimal response that you can send is:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No content
```

Note that there should be an empty line after above one (but markdown won't let me to enter empty line at the end of code block). You can send this in django using:

```
return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

But django will throw in some headers. You can get rid of them, but it's pointless...

Comment: Thanks! That is all I need to know :)

Answer (score 2):

What you did is a proper way to handle the client "not needing anything" after sending a request to the server.

However, you generally would want to supply the client with some sort of success message/action, regardless of how simple, just for the sake of making it user friendly. It can get confusing for users when they push a button and it looks like nothing happens. On that same note, they should be given an error message when something goes wrong, that way they can tell something is wrong (and therefore tell you) much faster than if nothing happened at all.

Comment: Thank you! In my case the server is a raspberry pi next to the user starting a music player. So there is some kind of "response" (although it's not on the webpage). I still think about a unobtrusive notification on the webpage though.